# Long build time when building for Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, build, instruments

I am developing an app targeted for iPad. The app is not particularly big or complex.

Whenever I run the app it builds in under one minute (even after Clean). Whenever I try to profile the app it builds about 12 minutes before Instruments appear. Most of this time Xcode shows `Building 139 of 139 files`.

The app has some image resources, uses Core Data, uses five 3rd-party "libraries" (included as source code files).

Why building for Profile takes so long? How can I make Xcode build faster?

**EDIT:**

Most of the time is spent while two strings like the following

```
CompileC ***.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

are shown in build log in gray color.

Comment: What specific build messages are you seeing (if you set the build output view scope bar options to "All" (as opposed to "Recent") and "All Messages" (as opposed to "All Issues" or "Errors Only")? Please select the line corresponding to operation that took the 12 minutes and expand it by clicking the little icon on the right. That log message will be the most important info for answering your question.

Comment: @ipmcc please see my update to the question

Comment: Welp, that means it's a compile operation that's taking forever. I have seen cases where Release compilation can take drastically longer than Debug compilation, but they tend to be pretty weird and 12x longer is really weird.  You might try sampling the offending clang process from the command line with `sample`. That might give you some hint of what was going on... but it might not. If you can distill down a good test case, I'm sure the clang guys at Apple would love for you to file a Radar at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @ipmcc thank you. I've changed what includes what and no it looks like the issue is caused by classes derived from `NSManagedObject` with about 200 properties (unfortunately, I have to have such many)

Comment: @ipmcc I found the cause and added my solution as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the cause in my case.

I have three classes in my app derived from `NSManagedObject` and these classes have about 200 properties each.

Since the data comes from web service, these classes contain some code like this:

```
- (void) fillFrom:(NSDictionary*)dict
{
    self.id = [dict valueForKey:KEYS[0]];
    self.jobUid = [dict valueForKey:KEYS[1]];
    self.manufacturer = [dict valueForKey:KEYS[2]];
    self.model = [dict valueForKey:KEYS[3]];
    ...
}
```

Obviously, I could do better but at the time the code is as the above. One assignment for each property. About 200 assignments in one method.

**THE CAUSE:**

`KEYS` is a define.

```
#define KEYS  @[ @"ID", @"JID", ... ]
```

Basically, 200 assignments are not only assignments. A copy of large auto-released array of strings is also created behind the scenes.

I changed the define to

```
NSString* KEYS[] = { @"ID", @"JID", ..., nil };
```

then adapted some other code that uses the KEYS and voila, profile builds are almost as fast as ordinary debug ones.

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to prepare a small test project to file but posting this in hope my experience might be useful for somebody else.